# Ubuntu VirtualBox seamless mode doesn't work well

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, windows-10

My host environment is Win10 and my Guest env is Ubuntu 15.10.

Though I installed guest additions, seamless mode doesn't work well; I can activate it and it shows only open windows, but doesn't combine Win and Ubuntu - The Unity bar is not on the left side of the screen and the top bar is not on the top...

Please, is there something you would recommend me of checking?

Note: I've already installed guest tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a misunderstanding of what seamless mode does and how it behaves. The main purpose of seamless mode is to make desktop apps on the virtual machine visually appear as though they are running on the host's desktop. This doesn't include desktop items such as the unity bar.

[This how-to article](http://www.howtogeek.com/171145/use-virtualboxs-seamless-mode-or-vmwares-unity-mode-to-seamlessly-run-programs-from-a-virtual-machine/) includes screenshots that appear to confirm this.

Comment: So, in theory if I closed all the Open (guest) windows on the Host's domain, I must leave seamless mode and open them again?

Comment: Seamless mode is just a viewing technology afaik. What you say seems like it would be true. I can't tell you for certain as I don't use use that mode due to issues like this. (Window's Virtual PC had a similar technology and handled edge cases such as when an app was shutdown or needed to be started later and kept the illusion intact better than other virtual machine software. But those were built around the idea that the guest OS would always be Windows XP and tuned accordingly.)